# Render Paper Form in Survey123

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-survey123

I have been tasked with converting several inspection reports into digital surveys using ArcGIS Survey123 that have, up until this point, been completed on a physical paper form. The form in question is a list of items that all have the same Yes/No responses. Ideally, my digital form would have a table of all the items and the ability to simply select 'Yes' or 'No' for each, and then a date field that displays the last time it was modified. However, it seems that this kind of table formulation is not possible in ArcGIS.

My current solution is a list of groups, one for each item, that contains the questions necessary for each. This is adequate, but it has the drawback that every item must be inspected every time the survey is opened.

Another solution that I wish to try is having the list of items in a dropdown, where the inspector selects the item in question and submits one survey response for each item. A drawback of this approach is that it is not easy to tell which items have already been inspected. I've considered including a "Last Inspected" field that autopopulates with the date of the last response for that item, but I am unsure if this is possible in Survey123 either.

Does ArcGIS have a simple solution for this scenario?[image: Something like this, where the 'Yes' and 'No' columns persist from previous responses, would be perfect.]

Comment: I think you want to look into repeats. Are you using Survey123 Connect? [repeats](https://community.esri.com/t5/esri-training-videos/arcgis-survey123-adding-repeats-to-your-survey/td-p/1271505#:~:text=Repeats%20are%20useful%20any%20time,54%2C%20in%20March%202023.)

Comment: I am using Survey123 Connect. The repeat method would work but the drawback is that it would still be clumsy for users to keep track of which items they have already inspected. I would love a format that is almost like a digital clipboard where they can check off and "save" each item's response as they go. If this is simply impossible, would I be able to set up a dropdown of items so that it was removed from the list once a response for it had been submitted?

Comment: [this thread](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-questions/remove-an-entry-or-item-from-the-dropdown-list/td-p/829354) discusses removing options from a list when they have been used already. It looks like there are a few different ways to set up list items so they are restricted once they have been used already. If you want to set it up like the survey form you will need to use [grid formatting](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-blog/survey123-tricks-of-the-trade-groups-grids-and/ba-p/895267)

Answer (score 0):

In the appearance column of your group's `begin_group` field, select 'field-list' or 'table-list' to view the selections as a choice grid or table grid of your questions. If you want to work with existing records to view previous inspections and populate the LastEdited field, you need use URL parameters to open the form in edit mode and supply a globalID. You will have an easier time if you link to the survey in the feature service popup in a web map so you can pass a selected feature's globalID to the survey form as a URL parameter.

In the popup configuration of your feature layer in a web map, add text like 'Update Record' or something intuitive/descriptive and then link the text to the the survey URL and add ***?mode=edit&globalId=globalid*** to the end of the hyperlink (the globalId call is case sensitive on both sides of the = sign. I would also recommend  storing your feature geometry and static information in the feature service, but store your inspection questions as a repeat(related table) in order to maintain access to multiple inspections.  With this method you are not limited to the Survey123 form interface- you can access feature popups (and the form via the popup link) in mobile apps, dashboards, web maps, etc. Survey123 URL parameters are discussed [here](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-blog/survey123-tricks-of-the-trade-web-form-url/ba-p/894722)